# What is the default number of transactions a full node have in its mempool?

Tags: bitcoind, full-node, mempool

Is there a default limit to the number of transactions a node can keep in its memory pool? Or do we have to explicitly declare `maxmempool=xyz` to restrict the number of transactions a node can have in its memory pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory pool (mempool) is not limited to a specific transaction count, but limited by the amount of data the deserialized transactions take up in the node's memory. The default memory pool limit is [300 MB](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/1c86ed41483471929840eec09b93d7de3a4aeacf/src/policy/policy.h#L32). The limit can be configured by passing `-maxmempool <n>` where the `n` is the number of megabytes allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The default mempool limit is 100MB. Not limiting at all would be a significant denial of service risk. Raising the limit will increase the performance of your node in some situations, lowering it will reduce the resource usage by a small amount.